# .htaccess in subfolder of images being ignored

Tags: apache, .htaccess

After a recent hacking attack, I want to put a .htaccess in a subfolder (called /images)

The root has its own .htaccess for the whole site

This htaccess I am putting in /images is

```
<Files ~ "\.(pdf|jpq|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)$">
   order deny,allow
   allow from all
</Files>
```

however I can still (using the website) upload a .DOC file with no problems to /images

Can anyone advise why this .htaccess is being ignored, or does the one at root take absolute preference and this is just ignored by the system

Comment: Please also be aware of steganographic based attacks. 1) Apache web server configuration advice from popular hosting providers, blog authors and the like still gives configuration advice where file names containing .php anywhere in their name will be processed as PHP. 2) PHP code can trivially be added to Jpeg exif tags. 3) The first 2 bytes of a jpeg file is sufficient to have PHP file classification functions report a file as a jpeg.The result is that uploading a file such avatar.php.jpg could result in PHP execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to deny from all everything else:

```
<Files ~ "\.(pdf|jpq|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)$">
   order deny,allow
   allow from all
</Files>

Deny from all
```

Comment: I was still allowed (using the web uploader) to upload a .TXT file